# What is the best way to clear unused Cassandra directories

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Why cassandra's gc didn't delete unused directories of column family during compaction? How can I delete them safely?

I have a 5 nodes Cassandra cluster:

```
# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.97.18.21  5.13 GiB   256          60.4%             8a6828d8-db43-4722-82fd-dd37ec1c25a1  rack1
UN  10.97.18.23  7.53 GiB   256          60.4%             adb18dfd-3cef-4ae3-9766-1e3f17d68588  rack1
UN  10.97.18.22  8.3 GiB    256          62.8%             1d6c453a-e3fb-4b3b-b7c1-689e7c8fbbbb  rack1
UN  10.97.18.25  5.1 GiB    256          60.1%             c8e4a4dc-4a05-4bac-b4d2-669fae9282b0  rack1
UN  10.97.18.24  7.97 GiB   256          56.3%             f2732a23-b70a-41a5-aaaa-1be95002ee8a  rack1
```

I have a keyspace 'loan_products' with only one column family 'events':

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> 
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACE loan_products ;

CREATE KEYSPACE loan_products WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE loan_products.events (
    persistence_id text,
    partition_nr bigint,
    sequence_nr bigint,
    timestamp timeuuid,
    timebucket text,
    event blob,
    event_manifest text,
    message blob,
    meta blob,
    meta_ser_id int,
    meta_ser_manifest text,
    ser_id int,
    ser_manifest text,
    tag1 text,
    tag2 text,
    tag3 text,
    used boolean static,
    writer_uuid text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((persistence_id, partition_nr), sequence_nr, timestamp, timebucket)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sequence_nr ASC, timestamp ASC, timebucket ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have no snapshots at all:

```
# nodetool listsnapshots
Snapshot Details: 
There are no snapshots
```

Column family has default **gc_grace_seconds = 864000** (10 days), so gc had to remove tombstones etc., but they are still exist on filesystem. Parallel-ssh shows:

```
[1] 11:50:34 [SUCCESS] 10.97.18.21
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:01 events-a83b3be0e61711e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:02 events-bbedb500e61c11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:08 events-48c2b750e61d11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:19 events-16c0b670e65011e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв 15 11:46 events-c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196

[2] 11:50:34 [SUCCESS] 10.97.18.22
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:00 events-a83b3be0e61711e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:01 events-bbedb500e61c11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:08 events-48c2b750e61d11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:19 events-16c0b670e65011e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв 15 11:49 events-c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196

[3] 11:50:34 [SUCCESS] 10.97.18.23
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:00 events-a83b3be0e61711e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:01 events-bbedb500e61c11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:07 events-48c2b750e61d11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:19 events-16c0b670e65011e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв 15 11:48 events-c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196

[4] 11:50:34 [SUCCESS] 10.97.18.25
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв  9 15:08 events-a83b3be0e61711e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв  9 15:08 events-bbedb500e61c11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв  9 15:08 events-48c2b750e61d11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв  9 15:08 events-16c0b670e65011e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв 15 11:45 events-c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196

[5] 11:50:34 [SUCCESS] 10.97.18.24
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:00 events-a83b3be0e61711e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 13:01 events-bbedb500e61c11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:08 events-48c2b750e61d11e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 дек 21 19:19 events-16c0b670e65011e7a2863103117dd196
drwxr-xr-x. 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 янв 15 11:50 events-c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196
```

As i see only one directory with id **c156cc40e65111e7a2863103117dd196** is in use, last update was on January 15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Cassandra takes a snapshot whenever a column family is dropped. This is by design to protect accidental truncation (deletion of all records in a table) or accidental drop of that table. The parameter in Cassandra.yaml controlling this is auto_snapshot

> Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
>   or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true
>   should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
>   lose data on truncation or drop. 
>   **auto_snapshot: true**

So based on the screenshot you have shown, looks like the "events" table was dropped atleast 4 times and recreated. So the proper way to clean this up would be to first figure out the correct UUID used by Cassandra for a given table in keyspace. In your case, the query would be

```
select id from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name = 'loan_products' and table_name = 'events' ;
```

Now remove the other table directories manually by "rm -rf" for the UUID's that doesn't correspond in the above output.

Also the reason "nodetool listsnapshots" isn't giving any snapshots, because the active table doesn't have any. But if you go to any of the other 4 "events" table directory and do a "ls -ltr" you should be able to find snapshot directories inside them, which were created as the table was dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You're right, the whole keyspace _loan_products_ with _events_ column family within really was dropped and recreated several times. Unfortunately, `nodetool cleanup` did nothing and every 5 directories still exist on each node.

Comment: Glad to know, can you please accept the answer, the small tick mark. Also the reason nodetool cleanup doesn’t do anything other cleaning up sstables in live table. Since these were snapshots of dropped tables, it has to be cleaned up manually.

Comment: Of course your answer is correct. But i don't understand should i just `rmdir` them? It's ok, but how can i choose right ids? File modification date provided by `ls -ltr` doesn't look like the best way to do this

Comment: You can query Cassandra, for correct UUID used for a given table in a keyspace as follows. select id from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name = 'loan_products' and table_name = 'events' ; Then manually "rm -rf" the other directories. Will udpate my answer to reflect this for a +1

Comment: Great! That was the target! Unforturnately my reputation does not allow +1 to your answer. Anyway, thank you so much!